# What kind of lambda expression syntax is this in Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda

This is from one question about lambda expression. I'm baffled with the syntax in line `check((h, l) -> h > l, 0);`:

The `check()` function requires a Climb object and an int. The line above does not provide any Climb object. And what does `h > l, 0` mean?

```
interface Climb {
  boolean isTooHigh(int height, int limit);
}

class Climber {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    check((h, l) -> h > l, 0);
  }
  private static void check(Climb climb, int height) {
    if (climb.isTooHigh(height, 1)) 
      System.out.println("too high");
    else 
      System.out.println("ok");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Climb` interface respects the contract of a [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html), that is, an interface with a single abstract method.

Hence, an instance of `Climb` can be implemented using a lambda expression, that is, an expression that takes two ints as parameters and returns a boolean in this case.

`(h, l) -> h > l` is the lambda expression that implements it. `h` and `l` are the parameters (`int`) and it will return whether `h > l` (so the result is indeed a `boolean`). So for instance you could write:

```
Climb climb = (h, l) -> h > l;
System.out.println(climb.isTooHigh(0, 2)); //false because 0 > 2 is not true
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, `(h, l) -> h > l` is a lambda expression where the result is of a boolean type and the `0` is the second argument of `check`, which is unrelated to the lambda expression itself; the `0` does not belong to the lambda expression as such.

Comment: How can a boolean be cast to a Climb object in the call to `check()`? I don't understand.

Comment: @FukuzawaYukio sound like you aren't familiar with lambda expressions implementing functional interfaces. Go learn about it :).

Answer (score 1):

`(h, l) -> h > l` is the climb object. It is a lambda that returns true when the first argument (h) is greater than the second (l). `0` is the int, and the comma separates the arguments.

Comment: How come `(h,l) -> h>l` is the Climb object? I can only see that it's a boolean and a boolean cannot be cast to a Climb object.

Comment: @FukuzawaYukio the lambda `(h, l) -> h > l` can be (and is) interpreted as the funtional interface `Climb` as it matches `boolean isTooHigh(int height, int limit);`

Comment: It's a lambda with a boolean as its return type. In the end, that's all a Climb object is, a function from two ints to a boolean. Java apparently has special syntactic sugar to convert such lambdas to anonymous implementations of an interface.